# Universal path for Chrome on *nix systems?

Tags: chrome

I'm looking to write a shell script that will detect all of the common places to find:

- Google Chrome
- Chromium

Installed for any given *Nix distribution.

The common ones I know of are:

- `/usr/bin/google-chrome`
- `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`
- `/usr/bin/chromium`
- `/usr/bin/chrome`
- On `PATH`

Is there a more official list somewhere? How is chromedriver doing this same logic does anyone know?

Comment: You need to consider two things: how is the binary named, and where is it stored. Currently you only cover the first.

Comment: any chance you can craft this comment up into an answer with what i'm missing?

Comment: by the way, i'm only looking for the "standard" place they would be found. I don't have to cover any custom, non-typical scenarios. I'm just trying to do as good of a job as chromedriver does when finding a suitable chrome executable.

Comment: I would at least go through PATH

Comment: good idea. i'll add that to the list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chromedriver looks for files in the following locations:

- `/usr/local/sbin`
- `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/sbin`
- `/usr/bin`
- `/sbin`
- `/bin`
- `/opt/google/chrome`

File names that it searches for are:

- `google-chrome`
- `chrome`
- `chromium`
- `chromium-browser`

The relevant code is [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome/chrome_finder.cc?q=chrome_finder&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=52).